# Modify action without deleting superclass actions

Tags: ios, landscape

### The Problem

I have made a subclass of UIViewController that handles landscape mode, then I subclassed my subclass, that is shown to the user. Now, I wan't to add a subclass in the landscape view, and have the size the same as the landscape view, but in order to get the frame I need to add the action

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
```

which I also used in my first subclass. However, when I do this, it ignores all the code in the superclass, and does that one thing (get the frame)

### What I CAN do

- I can get the landscape frame with a piece of code, like `[[UIScreen mainScreen].landscapeFrame` or something like that (if it exists)
- Rewrite the code from the superclass in the subclass (but then, what's the point to have a superclass?)

### Update / Fix

Silly me, I forgot to add `[super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: fromInterfaceOrientation];` Credit goes to Sanjay Chaudhry for noticing that, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call Super's method in the overwritten method:

```
[super didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: fromInterfaceOrientation];
```